# EC2 instance user data script does not finish running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running a Ruby on Rails app on an EC2 instance in an autoscaling group.  I am launching this instance with an AMI I created with packages needed to run the app.  To launch the app, I need to run two scripts from the app repository in order to launch the web server.

I have written a user data script that runs on the EC2 instance when it launches.  However, the load balancer that this autoscaling group is associated with returns a '502 Bad Gateway' response after launching the instance.  If I check the log file located at `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`, I can see that the last script almost finishes, but does not launch the web server app.  If I log in to the server as 'ec2-user' and run the script with `sudo ./directory/scriptname`, the script runs, the web server (Puma in this case) runs correctly, and valid HTTP responses are returned by the load balancer when I navigate to the load balancer IP in a browser window.

Below is the server log output run from the (non-terminating) user data script upon starting the EC2 instance:

```
+ sudo bash script/server
The RAILS_ENV variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
The DATABASE_NAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Starting tracks_db_1 ...
Starting tracks_db_1 ... done
Creating tracks_web_run ...
Creating tracks_web_run ... done
```

Below is the terminal output when I ssh into this machine and successfully run that exact same command as ec2-user in the same directory:

```
$ sudo bash script/server
WARNING: The RAILS_ENV variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The DATABASE_NAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Creating tracks_web_run ... done
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.3.4 application starting in production
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 5.2.2 (ruby 2.7.1-p83) ("Fettisdagsbulle")
*  Min threads: 5
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: production
*          PID: 9
* Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Why is the command failing when run as root via the user data script, but succeeds when run via ssh as ec2-user?

Comment: What is the script?

Comment: Link to repository:

[tracks/script/server](https://github.com/TracksApp/tracks/blob/master/script/server)